# How to make the controller visible to Spring framework in Hybris?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

When I add an AddOn for a Specific Storefront.
You should then edit trendingaddon-web-spring.xml and add a tag to make the controller visible to Spring framework.How to make?

Comment: Support me, please

Answer (score 1):

This is the statement you are looking for. You have to add your component to the context and rebuild your platform with `ant clean all`

```
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.yourproject.youraddon.controllers"/>
```

Comment: So no definition for bean of controller?

Comment: You can use @Controller annotation or configure it in XML